# Client loses messages when sending too many in a short time

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-4.5, signalr.client

Server broadcasts messages like below:

```
protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
    if (_messagesToSent == 0)
    {
        int.TryParse(data, out _messagesToSent);
    }
    else
        return Task.Delay(0);

    // Broadcast data to all clients
    return new TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
        {
            _log.InfoFormat("Starting broadcasting of {0} messages.", _messagesToSent);
            int sentMessages = 0;

            if (_messagesToSent > 0)
                Connection.Broadcast(GetInfoMessage());

            while (_messagesToSent > 0)
            {
                Connection.Broadcast(GetDataMessage(sentMessages));
                _messagesToSent--;
                sentMessages++;
                if (sentMessages % 1000 == 0)
                    _log.InfoFormat("{0} messages of total {1} messages sent.", sentMessages,
                                    sentMessages + _messagesToSent);
            }
            _log.InfoFormat("{0} messages were sent.", sentMessages);
        });
}
```

Basic idea is in the beginning server receives message from client with number of messages to sent. Then in the while loop it broadcasts this amount of messages and does some logging. 
Client is also simple it just counts number of received messages and logs input data:

```
private void ConnectionOnReceived(string s)
{
    ReceivedMessagesCount++;
    _log.Info(s);
}
```

I did several tests:

- broadcasting up to 1000 messages works fine, client receives all the messages
- broadcasting 2000 messages, client receives only about 1500 messages
- broadcasting 10K messages, same thing about 1500-1600 messages received

Tests were performed locally and with Azure, when server was hosted in cloud service.

So, what am I doing wrong? Did I missed something in the configuration or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending messages faster than your client can receive them causing your client to miss messages.

When 1000 messages or less are broadcast, your client receives all the messages because SignalR has a `DefaultMessageBufferSize` of 1000. This can be changed via SignalR's `IConfigurationManager`, e.g.:

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 2000;
```

However, chaning the `DefaultMessageBufferSize` is only a band-aid, since if you continuously send messages faster than your client can receive them, you will overrun a buffer of any size.

The real solution involves throttling the rate at which you send messages. This throttling could be achieved by having your client periodically send ACKs back to your `PersistentConnection` indicating how many messages it has received.

Comment: thanks @halter73. i did just for some testing, so DefaultMessageBufferSize is fine for me.

Comment: Ok, I agree with halter73 to a certain degree - but consider this scenario:

The client is on a 3G/4G connection, and signal reception can be of variable quality. So, whenever the signal reception falls, the queue on the server will start to build up, but the server will chew through it as soon as the client gets a decent signal again. 

Therefore, having a higher DefaultMessageBufferSize might be good in many situations. But still, you must take into consideration how much available memory the server has and how many clients that will potentially connect to the server etc.